# Singly Linked List bubble sort

Tags: java, linked-list, bubble-sort, singly-linked-list

I have implemented Singly linked list in my code and i have to sort the list.
But my code does not work, it stucks in an infinite loop. I have to compare nodes according to their id in ascending order.

I cant use arrays.
This is my SLL node implementation.

```
  class SLLNode implements Comparable<SLLNode> {
    protected int id;
    protected int plata;
    protected SLLNode succ;

    public SLLNode(int id,int plata, SLLNode succ) {
        this.id = id;
        this.plata=plata;
        this.succ = succ;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(SLLNode o) {
        return o.id - this.id;
    }
}

public static void sort(SLL lista){
    SLLNode current;
    boolean check = true;
    while(check) {
        current = lista.getFirst();
        check = false;

        while(current.succ != null)
        {
            if(current.compareTo(current.succ) > 0)
            {
                SLLNode temp = current;
                current=current.succ;
                current.succ=temp;
                check = true;
            }
            current = current.succ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI you should avoid bubble sort. It is one of the worst sorting algorithms, with complexity of O(n^2). _"Although the algorithm is simple, it is too slow and impractical for most problems"_ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is here:

```
            // Take a copy of current.
            SLLNode temp = current;
            // Step to next.
            current=current.succ;
            // Point temp (old current) to new next <----- Added this.
            temp.succ = current.succ;
            // Point next's successor to current.
            current.succ=temp;
            // Remember to check again.
            check = true;
```

You are missing changing `temp.succ`. You need to set it to `current.succ` at the appropriate place.

In summary - to swap two nodes a and b you need to do the following:

- Set a.succ = b.succ <--- You missed this.
- Set b.succ = a

Without sample implementation of your linked list I cannot test this.

Comment: Now it does not stuck in infinite loop, but it prints only the half of the numbers of list.

Comment: @kirkharamiler - That's a different problem.

Comment: what do you mean by different problem. It can be some other problem in implementation ?

Comment: @kirkharamiler - I mean you should post that as a new question.

Comment: Ok. I posted new question. Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

node *sorted_list(node *head) 
   {

```
node *index1,*index2;
enter code here
for(index1=head;index1->next!=NULL;index1=index1->next)
{
for(index2=index1->next;index2!=NULL;index2=index2->next) 
{
if(index1->data>index2->data) 
{
int temp=index1->data;
index1->data=index2->data;
index2->data=temp;
}
}
}
return head;
```

}